# Problems with deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I am having difficulty deploying my application to Heroku (using the free 5MB space plan). The commands I have used are:

`heroku create`, `git push heroku master`, and `heroku rake db:migrate`. All of which worked fine. I can see my startpage. I got postgresql running with a user model using devise gem. I can even access my sign_up and sign_in views.

However, after sign_up or sign_in I get a 500 error.

Note that this doesnt happen in development mode. Any advice?

Comment: check your logs via heroku logs

Comment: thx for the advice. It gives me "Started POST "/users"register" ...........Completed in 5ms. Seems fine. Below this it says: "Name Error (uninitialized constant Devise::Encryptors::Bcrypt)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the error you're receiving with `Devise::Encryptors::BCrypt`, check out [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/issue/697).